# IOS Google push notification not working in production

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, swift2, apple-push-notifications

**But i get the registration id in development enviornment and message i get is this**

```
{"multicast_id":8145067860904395870,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1452842547360715%bc92eed1bc92eed1"}]}
```

and i sucessfully recieve the message

**But when i try the same thing in production enviornment i get this message**

```
{"multicast_id":8861850059359760561,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}
```

and no nitification is recieved.

I have tried every thing from gentrating new provivioning profile to cleaning build folder  and using it but in production notification is not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google push notification not working in production](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34806142/google-push-notification-not-working-in-production)

Comment: please delete this question, as you've already asked and answered it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34806142/google-push-notification-not-working-in-production